# Why do I get an error installing Nokogiri on Ubuntu ec2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nokogiri

I'm trying to use `bundle install`, but it gets stuck installing Nokogiri. It says:

```
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
  nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
```

But, when I try `ruby -v`, it says:

```
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-linux]
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: are you using RVM, u may want to choose the correct ruby

Comment: if you using rvm, try `rvm use 1.9.3 --default`

Comment: Add the output of `gem env` to your question. We need to know what it knows about your Ruby environment. Also, if `rvm info` outputs anything useful append that output too.

Answer (score 0):

The new 1.6.0 doesn't seem to be compatible. I used the old 1.5.10 and it works. Thanks.